# Document ID feature

Tags: document-id

I have a situation where i will need to have unique file-names for all documents, otherwise i risk files with same names will overwrite each other whenever a user uploads a new document with the same name. Basicly what i want is a unique titel for the document as soon as it is added to the library.

Is this what the Document ID feature does?

I activated the Document ID feature, but nothing happend! I also made sure the settings were right, but still no ID was added to the files, anyone know why?

Could i achive this by doing something else? Workflow is not an option, because the users will not have the appropriate permissions in this library.

This is a Sharepoint Online environment.

thx.

Answer (score 0):

In a document library, two files of the same filename can't exist. Period.

The Document ID feature, just give a unique ID throughout the site collection, and has nothing to do with the first sentence.

We had the same problem and we solved it using a "bucket" list, just like the dropoff library. The user saves the file to the bucket list.

When all the fields have been filled, an event receiver (C#) checks if a file with the same filename exists in the destination list and adds (1) (2) (3) to the filename. Then it copies the file to the destination list.
Last step, the file is deleted from the bucket.

Comment: Actually, you *can* have two files with the same filename in a library, if they're in different folders. This recently caused us some confusion when a user, rather than simply editing a document in place, saved it to their hard drive, edited, then re-uploaded it, but picked the wrong folder at upload time: we use folders for security settings - e.g. `My Team Secured` folder, `Public` folder, etc. - and our views are all set to "Show all items without folders" so that each user sees all the documents they have access to.